# CSS Rearranging Specific elements to be side by side, but stacked when using mobile device/width too small?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've been working on this nutrition calculator and am having trouble formatting the CSS to optimize data visualization. I've tried adjusting the divs and adding containers, but for some reason it just leads to overlaps I don't understand how to fix.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/q024go3v/

```js
var  stocks= [
  ["Beef (80/20) raw","oz",115.4451262,3.293742347,72,4.85,5.65,0,2.142,19,20,0.0001275510204,0.375,0.75,22.15988372,0.3768292943,4  ],
  ["Beef (90/10) raw","oz",115.4451262,3.293742347,50,5.65,2.83,0,1.109,19,18,0.0001275510204,0.375,0.75,22.15988372,0.3768292943,4  ],
  ["Chicken breast","oz",32.39053977,0.3923520408,34,6.38,0.74,0,0.16,13,21,0.01631172356,0.10625,0.2125,3.149953226,0.3765300698,4  ],
  ["Chicken thighs/legs","oz",32.39053977,0.3923520408,125,2.72,12.54,0,3.431,14,30,0.01631172356,0.10625,0.2125,3.149953226,0.3765799405,4  ],
  ["Milk (whole)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.146234933,19,0.96,0.99,1.54,0.569,13,3,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2415694159,8  ],
  ["Milk (2%)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.06133157758,15,1.06,0.58,1.54,0.363,16,2,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2417190282,8  ],
  ["Pizza (cheese)","slice",42,0.976332736,285,12.19,10.37,3.83,4.778,640,18,0.00001071428571,2.98828125,5.9765625,36.85985865,0.466697922,4  ],
  ["Ice Cream","cup",32.59312,0.6191784396,274.71344,4.6095984,14.4806576,27.9835216,8.94913952,107.09168,55.87392,0.000003990994286,1.11311325,2.2262265,13.73003196,2.889031735,1  ],
  ["Milk (skim)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.05948052127,10,1.03,0.02,1.54,0.017,13,1,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2415694159,8  ],
  ["Eggs (large)","each",43.13341461,0.5215603261,78,6.29,5.3,0.2,1.633,62,186,0.001666666667,0.265625,0.53125,3.713549,0.1305756192,1  ],
  ["Lamb","oz",78.125,4.010117347,80,4.69,6.64,0,2.889,17,21,0.03333333333,0.3125,0.625,2.274815967,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Cheese (hard)","slice (oz)",37.44571072,1.35234933,105,6.59,8.41,0.14,5.32,159,27,0.000003571428571,0.99609375,1.9921875,12.28661955,0.1303337926,1  ],
  ["Yogurt","oz",5.833333333,0.09395993304,17,0.98,0.92,1.32,0.595,13,4,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2229453548,6  ],
  ["Greek yogurt, vanilla (nonfat)","fl oz",15,0.08285194565,22,2.45,0.05,1.01,0.038,10,1,8.928571429e-7,0.3984375,0.796875,3.071654888,0.1965527472,6  ],
  ["Chocolate","oz",127.316,0.1863325866,151,2.16,8.39,14.57,5.238,22,7,7.142857143e-8,0.019921875,0.03984375,1.601963425,1.345070603,1.45  ],
  ["Cacao","oz",179.739,0.625,136,1.19,8.51,15.45,5.032,3,0,0,0,0,3.390577585,1.418619303,1.45  ],
  ["Salmon (farmed)","oz",0.498125,0.56925,59,5.79,3.8,0,0.864,17,16,0.004464285714,0.078125,0.15625,0.5593288054,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Tuna (canned in oil)","oz",0.498125,0.1197485281,56,8.26,2.33,0,0.435,118,5,0.000270197828,1.0625,2.125,0.5593288054,0.3817664985,4  ],
  ["Mayo","oz",14.41309121,0.1237135815,193,0.27,21.22,0.16,3.318,180,12,0.0004166666667,0.06640625,0.1328125,0.92838725,0.1330741748,0.5  ],
  ["Pulled Pork raw","oz",44.84498316,0.7763814526,53,4.94,3.5,0,1.232,17,18,0.0005208333333,0.21875,0.4375,1.592371177,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Butter (salted)","oz",41.58720633,0.5919085938,203,0.24,22.95,0.02,14.537,182,61,0.0000075,2.091796875,4.18359375,25.80190106,0.121322241,1  ],
  ["Soy Burger","oz",21.8,0.048125,50,4.44,1.78,0.3,0.408,161,1,0,0,0,2.314125,0.03342563782,4  ],
  ["Vegan Nuggets (soy)","oz",21.8,0.048125,52,4.88,1.63,0.65,0.325,172,0,0,0,0,2.314125,0.06360340429,4  ],
  ["Soymilk (original)","fl oz",2.319532348,0.02445449777,17,1,0.54,1.21,0.063,16,0,0,0,0,1.168382863,0.1032302684,8  ],
  ["Tofu","oz",25.25,0.09625,23,2.82,1.49,0.2,0.26,1,0,0,0,0,4.62825,0.01698083545,4  ],
  ["Tempeh","oz",12.383064,0.0230998152,54,5.74,3.06,0,0.719,3,0,0,0,0,1.110771114,0.0001496122504,4  ],
  ["Mixed Nuts","oz",18.72285536,0.18425,172,5.53,15.17,1.42,2.271,1,1,0,0,0,1.019662873,0.1202597201,1  ],
  ["Bread","slice",9.735884788,0.1530147137,79,3.09,1.31,1.66,0.202,137,0,0,0,0,0.5625,0.1473592997,2  ],
  ["Lentils","oz",30.3684714,0.07425,33,2.55,0.11,0.51,0.015,1,0,0,0,0,2.287814892,0.04322383072,7.1  ],
  ["Black Beans","oz",30.3684714,0.141625,37,2.31,0.1,0.09,0.025,1,0,0,0,0,1.555714169,0.007668804863,7.1  ],
  ["Tomato Sauce","oz",3.13704,0.09375,11,0.47,0.06,1.37,0.008,57,0,0,0,0,0.4188459746,0.1188197409,8  ],
  ["Pinto Beans","oz",30.3684714,0.141625,40,2.55,0.18,0.09,0.038,0,0,0,0,0,0.9075003086,0.007618934113,7.1  ],
  ["French Fries","oz",2.9337142,0.0417335921,56,0.82,1.91,0.14,0.359,113,0,0,0,0,0.4200133922,0.01748707005,4  ],
  ["Peanut Butter","oz",36,0.2145,167,6.81,14.13,2.97,2.153,138,0,0,0,0,3.675378676,0.2583069893,1  ],
  ["Olive Oil","oz",21.77842536,0.2306145384,250,0,28.3,0,3.908,1,0,0,0,0,1.512500057,0.00004987075014,0.5  ],
  ["Banana","medium",6.440662244,0.1763699536,105,1.29,0.39,14.43,0.132,1,0,0,0,0,0.1768995697,1.221618974,1  ],
  ["Mixed vegetables","oz",2.41150377,0.125,18,0.81,0.04,0,0.009,10,0,0,0,0,3,0.0004987075014,4  ],
  ["Nutritional Yeast","g",0.08506329224,0.00706361088,3.9859577,0.5989518739,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5  ],
  ["Rice (white)","oz",25.46308329,0.34375,102,1.87,0.16,0,0.045,0,0,0,0,0,0.3995205753,0,2  ],
  ["Potatoes","oz",1.872285536,0.03575,16,0.73,0.03,0.2,0.007,3,0,0,0,0,0.06927480776,0.01708057695,5.3  ],
  ["Vegetable Oil","oz",17.70433203,0.125,205,0,23.8,0,19.937,0,0,0,0,0,5.300817694,0,0.5  ],
  ["Wheat (flour)","cup",40.44136758,0.1235081329,408,13.56,1.88,0.36,0.276,4,0,0,0,0,1.598082301,0.03067521945,0.25  ],
  ["Margarine","oz",9.915624199,0.06125,102,0.28,11.32,0,2.048,222,0,0,0,0,5.300817694,0.01107130653,1  ],
  ["Corn Syrup","fl oz",11.15931776,0.01728062914,109,0,0,29.31,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.4854914297,2.481282747,1  ],
  ["Sugar","oz",11.23371322,0.01503093504,110,0,0,28.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.4340729937,2.395731504,1  ],
  ["Corn (grain)","oz",6.74022793,0.0104375,103,2.67,1.34,0.18,0.189,10,0,0,0,0,0.4549631935,0.01573657573,1  ],
  ["Soda","fl oz",10.64647779,0.02494335117,13,0,0.08,3.05,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.1939638153,0.2582470824,12  ]
]
function Stock (data) {
  return {
    name: data[0],
    servingUnit: data[1],
    water: [data[2], ''],
    carbon: [data[3], ''],
    calories: [data[4], ''],
    protein: [data[5], 'g'],
    fat: [data[6], 'g'],
    saturatedFat: [data[8], 'g'],
    sugar: [data[7], 'g'],
    sodium: [data[9], 'mg'],
    cholesterol: [data[10], 'mg'],
    lives: [data[11], ''],
    feed: [data[12], ''],
    meals: [data[13], ''],
    land : [data[14], ''],
    healthcare : [data[15], ''],
    unitsPerServing: data[data.length - 1]
  }
}

stocks = stocks.map(Stock)

var $selects = $('.selectStock')
var $quantity = $('#numberOfStocks')
var $comparisonResult = $('.comparison .result')

$selects.each(function() {
  $(this).append(stocks.map(function(stock, i) {
    return new Option(stock.name, i)
  }))
})

function format(data, multiplier, digits,a) {
  data = data.slice()
  data[0] = (+(data[0] * multiplier).toFixed(digits)).toLocaleString();
    console.log(data);
  if(a=="bad" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="bad" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="good" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="good" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  return data.join(' ')
}

function format2(data, multiplier, digits,a) {
  data = data.slice()
  data[0] = (+(data[0] * multiplier).toFixed(digits)).toLocaleString();
    console.log(data);
  if(a=="use" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="use" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="emit" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="emit" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="consumegood" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="consumegood" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  return data.join(' ')
}
function stockFacts(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad","use") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad","emit") + ' pounds of carbon dioxide and methane equivalents <br>' +
    format(stock.calories, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' calories<br>' +
    format(stock.protein, quantity, 2,"good","consumegood") + ' of protein<br>' +
    format(stock.fat, quantity, 3,"bad","consume") + ' of fat<br>' +
    format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
    format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sugar<br>' +
    format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sodium<br>' +
    format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of cholesterol<br>' +
    format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad","save") + ' animal lives<br>' +
    format(stock.feed, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' pounds of feed<br>' +
    format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad","preserve") + ' meals made from feed<br>' +
    format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' square feet of land needed<br>' +
    "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad","save") + ' in projected healthcare costs<br>'
  ]
}

function stockFactsEnv(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad","use") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad","emit") + ' pounds of carbon dioxide and methane equivalents <br>' +
    format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' square feet of land needed<br>'
  ]
}

function stockFactsHealth(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.calories, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' calories<br>' +
    format(stock.protein, quantity, 2,"good","consumegood") + ' of protein<br>' +
    format(stock.fat, quantity, 3,"bad","consume") + ' of fat<br>' +
    format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
    format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sugar<br>' +
    format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sodium<br>' +
    format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of cholesterol<br>' +
    "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad","save") + ' in projected healthcare costs<br>'
  ]
}

function stockFactsSocial(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad","save") + ' animal lives<br>' +
    format(stock.feed, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' pounds of feed<br>' +
    format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad","preserve") + ' meals made from feed<br>'
  ]
}

function stockFacts2(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    "Use " + format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad","use") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    "Emit " + format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad","emit") + ' pounds of greenhouse gases<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.calories, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' calories<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.protein, quantity, 2,"good","consumegood") + ' of protein<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.fat, quantity, 3,"bad","consume") + ' of fat<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
   "Consume " +  format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sugar<br>' +
   "Consume " + format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sodium<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of cholesterol<br>' +
   "Require " +  format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad","save") + ' animal lives to produce your food<br>' +
    "Require " + format(stock.feed, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' pounds of feed to produce your food<br>' +
    "Be able to produce " + format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad","preserve") + ' meals made from feed<br>' +
    "Require " + format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' square feet of land to produce your food<br>' +
    "Cost the US healthcare system approximately " + "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad","save")
  ]
}

function stockFacts3(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    "Save " + format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad","use") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    "Emit " + format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad","emit") + ' pounds of greenhouse gases<br>' +
   "Save " +  format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad","save") + ' animals<br>' +
    "Feed " + format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad","preserve") + ' people<br>' +
    "Require " + format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' square feet of land<br>' +
    "Cost the US healthcare system approximately " + "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad","save")
  ]
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}

function updateAmount() {
  var quantity = +$quantity.val() 
    
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $result = $(this).nextAll('.result').empty()
    var $amount = $(this).prev().find('.servingUnit').empty()
    var stock = getStock(this)
    if (!stock) return
    var amount = quantity * stock.unitsPerServing
    
    $amount.text(' (' + amount + ' ' + stock.servingUnit + ')')
    
    $result.html(stockFacts(stock, amount))
  })
  
  var selected = [].map.call($selects, getStock)
  $comparisonResult.empty()
  if (!selected[0] || !selected[1]) return
  var diff = {}
  Object.keys(selected[0]).forEach(function (k) {
    if (/^(name|servingUnit|unitsPerServing)$/.test(k)) return
    var first = selected[0][k].slice()
    var second = selected[1][k].slice()
    first[0] *= selected[0].unitsPerServing
    second[0] *= selected[1].unitsPerServing
    diff[k] = [Math.abs(first[0] - second[0]), first[1], first[0] > second[0] ? 'more' : 'less']
  })
  $comparisonResult.html(stockFacts(diff, quantity));
 $('#env_result').html(stockFactsEnv(diff, quantity));
  $('#health_result').html(stockFactsHealth(diff, quantity));
  $('#soc_result').html(stockFactsSocial(diff, quantity));
 $('#year_result').html(stockFacts2(diff, quantity*365));
  $('#US_result').html(stockFacts3(diff,quantity*323148587));
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}
```

```css
.side {
  width: 300px;
}
.sideone {
  width: 300px;
}
h2
{
  display: inline-block;
}
.left
{
  float: right;
}
.comparison {
width: 50%;
}
.outer {
 display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.content
{
  width: 50%;
}
.color-red{
color:red;
background:transparent}
.color-green{
color:green;
background:transparent}

div {
background-color: white;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #173;
    overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

<style type="text/css">
 
#share-buttons img {
width: 35px;
padding: 5px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
display: inline;
}
 
</style>

<style type="text/css">
/* Hide AddToAny vertical share bar when screen is less than 980 pixels wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .a2a_floating_style.a2a_vertical_style { display: none; }
}
</style>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#ingredient">Ingredient Calculator</a>
  <a href="#meal">Meal Calculator</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#sources">Sources</a>
</div>
<br>
<label>
    Servings:
    <input type="number" id="numberOfStocks" value="1" min="0" />
  </label>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="side">
        <h2>First Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
        <select class="selectStock">
          <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2> vs. </h2>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="sideone">
        <h2>Second Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
        <select class="selectStock">
          <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id = "container" style = "width:100%">
  <div class="comparison">
      <h2>Total Breakdown:</h2>
      <br>
    <div id ="left" style = "float: left; width: 35%;">
      <h2><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Environment:</h2></div>
    <div id = "middle" style = "float: center; width: 50%; height: 100%;">
      <div id="env_result"></div></div>
    <h2><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i>   Health:</h2>
      <div id="health_result"></div>
    <div id = "right" style = "float:right; width: 25%;">
    <h2><img src="https://i.imgur.com/hiDscpk.png" width= 50px> Social:</h2>
      <div id="soc_result"></div></div>
      <br>
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
<br>
<h2>If you made this switch every day for a year, you would:</h2>
<div id="year_result">
</div>
<br>
<h2 class = "comparison">If everyone in America made this switch for just one meal, we would:</h2>
<div id="US_result">
</div>

<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_floating_style a2a_vertical_style" style="left:0px; top:150px;">
    <a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_pinterest"></a>
</div>

<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
```

As you can see, it doesn't look too pretty at the moment. Here is how I need to structure the elements:
[image: desktop] for desktop and

[image: mobile]

for mobile. There is probably a simple way to do this in CSS but I'm having trouble finding how to do it using online resources. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

First : Try to write the CSS in a separate CSS file. Makes maintenance easy and styles wont override.

use media query to set  to 100% and clear the float

Have created a example to help . Please take a look at plunkr link :

https://plnkr.co/edit/DyTvCh3XzWoYx8MfXnIg?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar"> Navbar </div>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="box"> Box 1 </div>
      <div class="box">Box 2 </div>
      <div class="box"> Box 3</div>
      <div class="box"> Box 4 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-container"> 
      <div class="box-2"> Box 5 </div>
      <div class="box-2"> Box 6</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS :

```
*{
    padding : 0;
      margin : 0;
}
body{
  height : 100vh;
}

.navbar{
  height : 50px;
  width : 100%;
  background : green;
  text-align : center;
  color : white;
}

.box{
  height : 250px;
  width : 20%;
  background : blue;
  display : inline-block;
  text-align : center;
  font-size : 1.5em;
  color : white;
}

.box-2{
  height : 250px;
  width : 48%;
  background : orange;
  display : inline-block;
    text-align : center;
  font-size : 1.5em;
  color : white;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .box{
    display : block;
    width : 100%;

  }

  .box-2{
    display : block;
    width : 100%;

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using codepen to make the site- is there a better way for that?

Comment: start creating website locally, create HTML ., Link css and javascript. That will be better.

Comment: Ok, thanks- I did that and it was pretty simple. What are the next steps?

Comment: Have added HTML and CSS to the answer.  Have added a working example plunkr link too. Please take a look.

Comment: That's great, looks like exactly what I need. How do I make the boxes go to the right instead of the left? margin-right: 100%?